# Optimize query to get distinct records

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14, babelfish

I have the following query to get product sold count.

Present Query: Which gives duplicate records.

```
--(322212 rows affected) 
--00:00:08 Time Taken
SELECT pc.qty_typecode ,
        pc.prdcost, AS  prdcost ,
        pc.d1cost, AS  d1cost ,
        pc.d2cost, AS  d2cost ,
        pc.saledate
        ,COUNT(ps.pdt_soldsID) OVER ( PARTITION BY pc.saledate, qt.qtycvalue) AS pdt_soldsCOUNT 
FROM prdcost pc 
left JOIN qty_type qt ON  qt.qty_typecode = pc.qty_typecode and qt.classcode = pc.classcode 
left JOIN pdt_solds ps ON pc.qty_typecode = ps.qty_typecode and pc.classcode = ps.classcode and pc.saledate = ps.saledate
WHERE pc.classcode = 'CD901';
```

Execution Plan:

```
WindowAgg  (cost=47.12..34684.67 rows=212179 width=90) (actual time=5.950..7402.059 rows=322212 loops=1)
  ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=47.12..30971.54 rows=212179 width=33) (actual time=5.904..5850.861 rows=322212 loops=1)
        Sort Key: pc.saledate, qt.qtycvalue
        Presorted Key: pc.saledate
        Full-sort Groups: 544  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 28kB  Peak Memory: 28kB
        Pre-sorted Groups: 511  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 308kB  Peak Memory: 331kB
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.00..13668.98 rows=212179 width=33) (actual time=1.285..3704.330 rows=322212 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.57..1698.93 rows=13345 width=36) (actual time=1.203..187.022 rows=13345 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using pk_prdcost96e969d29d073e188a438d9bb770e4ae on prdcost pc  (cost=0.29..1329.04 rows=13345 width=31) (actual time=1.131..43.352 rows=13345 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((classcode)::"varchar" = 'CD901'::"varchar")
                    ->  Memoize  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=13345)
                          Cache Key: pc.classcode, pc.qty_typecode
                          Cache Mode: logical
                          Hits: 13316  Misses: 29  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 4kB
                          ->  Index Only Scan using ix_qty_typeqty_type4e1c5ab4d14a7b3776609e998f02177e on qty_type qt  (cost=0.27..0.29 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=1 loops=29)
                                Index Cond: ((classcode = (pc.classcode)::"varchar") AND (classcode = 'CD901'::"varchar") AND (qty_typecode = (pc.qty_typecode)::"varchar"))
                                Heap Fetches: 10
              ->  Memoize  (cost=0.43..4.37 rows=15 width=23) (actual time=0.191..0.259 rows=28 loops=13345)
                    Cache Key: pc.classcode, pc.qty_typecode, pc.saledate
                    Cache Mode: binary
                    Hits: 0  Misses: 13345  Evictions: 10092  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 4097kB
                    ->  Index Scan using ix_pdt_solds0ff36731c0b25757fbb5620cf6962faa on pdt_solds ps  (cost=0.42..4.36 rows=15 width=23) (actual time=0.189..0.248 rows=28 loops=13345)
                          Index Cond: ((saledate = pc.saledate) AND ((classcode)::"varchar" = (pc.classcode)::"varchar") AND ((classcode)::"varchar" = 'CD901'::"varchar") AND ((qty_typecode)::"varchar" = (pc.qty_typecode)::"varchar"))
Planning Time: 21.895 ms
Execution Time: 8395.226 ms
```

**Note**: Table `pdt_solds` is having duplicate records with distinct identity column `pdt_soldsID`.

To reduce duplicate records I have rewritten query as shown below:

Rewritten query: To reduce duplicate records.

```
--(14941 rows affected) 
--00:00:18 Time Taken
with cte as 
(
    select  classcode, saledate, qty_typecode
    ,COUNT(pdt_soldsID) pdt_soldsID
    from pdt_solds
    WHERE classcode = 'CD901'
    GROUP BY classcode, saledate, qty_typecode
)
SELECT  pc.qty_typecode,
        pc.prdcost,  AS  prdcost,
        pc.d1cost,  AS  d1cost,
        pc.d2cost,  AS  d2cost,
        pc.saledate
        , qt.qtycvalue
        , SUM(t.pdt_soldsID) OVER (PARTITION BY pc.saledate, qt.qtycvalue) AS pdt_soldsCOUNT
FROM prdcost pc
LEFT  JOIN  qty_type qt ON pc.qty_typecode = qt.qty_typecode AND pc.classcode = qt.classcode
LEFT JOIN cte t
ON  pc.classcode = t.classcode and pc.saledate = T.saledate and pc.qty_typecode = t.qty_typecode
WHERE pc.classcode = 'CD901';
```

Execution Plan:

```
WindowAgg  (cost=51338.54..51605.44 rows=14941 width=90) (actual time=16994.585..17051.169 rows=14941 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=51338.54..51371.90 rows=14941 width=33) (actual time=16994.537..16996.465 rows=14941 loops=1)
        Sort Key: pc.saledate, rt.qtycvalue
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1427kB
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=34306.49..50424.14 rows=14941 width=33) (actual time=3328.237..16715.227 rows=14941 loops=1)
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=34306.21..50054.25 rows=14941 width=35) (actual time=3328.142..16592.567 rows=14941 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (((pdt_solds.classcode)::"varchar" = (pc.classcode)::"varchar") AND ((pdt_solds.qty_typecode)::"varchar" = (pc.qty_typecode)::"varchar"))
                    Join Filter: (pc.saledate = pdt_solds.saledate)
                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2726548
                    ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=33553.59..48447.29 rows=56023 width=23) (actual time=2363.688..2534.878 rows=9643 loops=1)
                          Group Key: pdt_solds.classcode, pdt_solds.saledate, pdt_solds.qty_typecode
                          ->  Gather Merge  (cost=33553.59..46626.54 rows=112046 width=27) (actual time=2363.662..2473.792 rows=16560 loops=1)
                                Workers Planned: 2
                                Workers Launched: 2
                                ->  Sort  (cost=32553.57..32693.63 rows=56023 width=27) (actual time=2277.771..2278.778 rows=5520 loops=3)
                                      Sort Key: pdt_solds.saledate, pdt_solds.qty_typecode
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 660kB
                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 648kB
                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 564kB
                                      ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=25571.03..28135.11 rows=56023 width=27) (actual time=2123.986..2125.474 rows=5520 loops=3)
                                            Group Key: pdt_solds.classcode, pdt_solds.saledate, pdt_solds.qty_typecode
                                            Planned Partitions: 4  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1553kB
                                            Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1569kB
                                            Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1569kB
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on pdt_solds  (cost=0.00..12425.79 rows=170995 width=23) (actual time=0.551..518.896 rows=136878 loops=3)
                                                  Filter: ((classcode)::"varchar" = 'CD901'::"varchar")
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 106374
                    ->  Hash  (cost=552.44..552.44 rows=14941 width=31) (actual time=110.010..110.011 rows=14941 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1011kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on prdcost pc  (cost=0.00..552.44 rows=14941 width=31) (actual time=1.162..44.535 rows=14941 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((classcode)::"varchar" = 'CD901'::"varchar")
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 7970
              ->  Memoize  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=14941)
                    Cache Key: pc.classcode, pc.qty_typecode
                    Cache Mode: logical
                    Hits: 13316  Misses: 29  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 4kB
                    ->  Index Only Scan using ix_qty_typeqty_type4e1c5ab4d14a7b3776609e998f02177e on qty_type rt  (cost=0.27..0.29 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.044..0.045 rows=1 loops=29)
                          Index Cond: ((classcode = (pc.classcode)::"varchar") AND (classcode = 'CD901'::"varchar") AND (qty_typecode = (pc.qty_typecode)::"varchar"))
                          Heap Fetches: 10
Planning Time: 2.051 ms
Execution Time: 17109.260 ms
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query as an uncorrect syntax. The keyword AS must not have prior a comma character, rewrite as :

```
WITH 
cte AS 
(SELECT classcode, 
        saledate, 
        qty_typecode, 
        COUNT(pdt_soldsID) pdt_soldsID
 FROM   pdt_solds
 WHERE  classcode = 'CD901'
 GROUP  BY classcode, 
           saledate, 
           qty_typecode)
SELECT pc.qty_typecode, 
       pc.prdcost AS prdcost, 
       pc.d1cost AS d1cost, 
       pc.d2cost AS d2cost, 
       pc.saledate, 
       qt.qtycvalue, 
       SUM(t.pdt_soldsID) OVER(PARTITION BY pc.saledate, 
                                            qt.qtycvalue) AS pdt_soldsCOUNT
FROM   prdcost AS pc
       LEFT JOIN qty_type AS qt 
          ON pc.qty_typecode = qt.qty_typecode
             AND pc.classcode = qt.classcode
       LEFT JOIN cte AS t 
          ON pc.classcode = t.classcode
             AND pc.saledate = t.saledate
             AND pc.qty_typecode = t.qty_typecode
WHERE  pc.classcode = 'CD901';
```

The second WHERE clauseis stupid beacuse you have already filter in the CTE on "classcode = 'CD901'". So remove this WHERE clause.

Do you have **exactly** those index : ???

```
CREATE INDEX X001 ON pdt_solds (classcode, saledate, qty_typecode); 

CREATE INDEX X002 ON prdcost (classcode, saledate, qty_typecode) INCLUDE (prdcost, d1cost, d2cost

CREATE INDEX X003 ON qty_type (qty_typecode, classcode) INCLUDE (qtycvalue);
```

If not create them.